# LINQ query to return List<bool>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query from which I need to return list of `true` or `false` if condition gets satisfied on particular item at that index.

```
dataList = {100, 40, 10, 200};
var res = dataList.Select((item, index) => new { item, index }).Any(x => x.item > 50).ToList();
```

Problem in above approach is I am not able to add ToList() at the end. And without it its returning only true or false while I want a list of bool.

> Expected output - {true, false, false, true}

Comment: dataList typeof ?

Comment: @PranavPatel integer 
List<int> dataList = new List<int>{100, 40, 10, 200};

Comment: `Any(x => x.item > 50)` returns `bool`. You can't cast `bool` to list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a lot of unneeded code in your approach.
The overload of Select that takes an Index is not needed to just test if the *current* element in the sequence enumerated by Select is bigger than 50.

If you just want a list of booleans matching your integer array then it is just

```
int[] dataList = { 100, 40, 10, 200};
var res = dataList.Select(item => item > 50).ToList();

foreach(bool b in res)
   Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Finally, the call to Any is wrong. It returns true or false when an element in your list satisfy the condition and then STOPS the enumeration. It doesn't return an IEnumerable that you can meterialize with ToList().